# Bootstrap ul li

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to align my ul and put it in the right with Bootstrap but when I use :

```
<ul class="list-inline" class="pull-right">
  <li>S'inscrire</li>
  <li>Se connecter</li>
</ul>
```

Can anyone explain to me why it doesn't work?

Comment: share your working code here!

Comment: hi , you are using class , class two time . class="list-inline pull-right"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have two class attributes. The code should be:

```
<ul class="list-inline pull-right">
  <li>S'inscrire</li>
  <li>Se connecter</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ah, looks like this is it.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your page where you included bootstrap css

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>S'inscrire</li>
      <li>Se connecter</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Why do you wanna add `navbar` classes? It is totally irrelevant here, even though it "works".

Comment: @PraveenKumar not necessary, you can remove `navbar-nav` class